# C#: Why is this code populating this listView out of order?

Tags: c#, xml, listview

Can anyone see where I am going wrong here? Code is supposed to open an xml document, then based on the contents of each node, populate the columns of a ListView with the innertext of each node/attribute. The List view should look like this:

```
Item1   Item2   Item3
Item4   Item5   Item6
Item7   Item8   Item9
```

However its ending up like this:

```
Item7 Item2 Item5
Item4
Item1
```

The code producing this error is as follows:

```
private void openPasswordFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Xml.XmlDocument loadDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        loadDoc.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\database.xml");


        foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode descNode in loadDoc.SelectNodes("/Database/Account"))
        {
            lvItem = listView1.Items.Insert(index, descNode.Attributes["Description"].InnerText); ;
        }
        foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode userNode in loadDoc.SelectNodes("/Database/Account"))
        {
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(lvItem, userNode.Attributes["Username"].InnerText)); ;
        }
        foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode passNode in loadDoc.SelectNodes("/Database/Account"))
        {
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(lvItem, passNode.Attributes["Password"].InnerText)); ;
        }
        foreach(System.Xml.XmlNode node in loadDoc)
        {
            index += 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about the structure of the xml doc, but your foreach code is wrong.
If you are trying to add sub items for each parent then

```
    foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode descNode in loadDoc.SelectNodes("/Database/Account"))
    {
        lvItem = listView1.Items.Insert(index, descNode.Attributes["Description"].InnerText); ;
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(lvItem, userNode.Attributes["Username"].InnerText)); ;
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(lvItem, passNode.Attributes["Password"].InnerText)); ;
    }
```